# AngularJS, distinguish between drag and click events, and pass data to the click event

Tags: jquery, angularjs, typescript

I'm using the plugin [wheelZoom](https://www.jacklmoore.com/wheelzoom/) to scroll and zoom using the mouse wheel. Now i'm trying to add the ability to open the image in a new tab by clicking on it. The problem is that while `dragging`, a `click` event is thrown. I need to isolate the `drag` and `click` events to enable different capabilities. I've found a way to determine whats a `drag` and whats `click`. How can I pass an `event` or the object that is currently clicked to the function that handles clicks?

TS:

```
constructor(private $element: ng.IRootElementService) {
    angular.element(function () {
        const element = angular.element( document.querySelector( '#imageZoom' ) );
        let drag = false;
        element.bind('mousedown', () => drag = false);
        element.bind('mousemove', () => drag = true);
        element.bind('mouseup', () => console.log(drag ? 'drag' : this.openImgNewTab(noteObj)));

    });
}

private openImgNewTab(noteObj){
   //pass the event and\or the object that was clicked on?
   //...
  //.. open the image of the note in a new tab using noteObj.path

}
```

HTML:

```
<image-zoom class="thumbnail"
            id="imageZoom"
            image-url="{{ $ctrl.options.note.url}}">
</image-zoom>
```

Answer (score 0):

To discriminate the type of event use the `type` property of the `event` object:

```
element.on('mousedown mousemove mouseup click', (event) => {
    console.log(event.type);
});
```

For more information, see

- [jQuery API Reference - event.type](https://api.jquery.com/event.type/)